# CRM365: images do show in columns in Unified Interface

Tags: dynamics-crm-365

Subject: Display custom icons instead of values in list views

Under the Classic interface the icons are working fine as described in the documentation. However, if I switch to Unified Interface they are not displayed anymore.

Inspecting the page (visually and in the generated html) it looks that the space is indeed reserved for the image as DIV. So I suspect the code behind the page is not able to find/retrieve the images when in Unified Interface even if I supply the full URL of the picture.

Did anybody else encountered similar problems when moving from Classic to UI interface?

We are in an on-premise installation.

Comment: Are you doing this one? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/display-custom-icons-instead

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I used and it works fine in Classic interface. I suspect the images are not found by the Unified Interface although they are in the right place. I see the space (the DIV) in place in the View so the script works in UI, just images don't show.

Answer (score 0):

What type is your image? Is it PNG, JPEG, or GIF.

In new UI it should only be PNG and that too of size 16*16.

[Reference article to look into](https://d365goddess.com/d365-ce-adding-icons-to-views/)